# How to warmup telegram bot c# every 15 mins?

Tags: c#, .net-core, telegram-bot

I need to warm up telegram c# bot every 15 minutes, because it's going to sleep if some time didn't recieve calls. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Could you explain which framework are you using? Please include some code that could help to foccus better the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use uptimerobot.com which will call after some minutes your empty api method